# MySql conditional short descriptions

Tags: mysql

Please help me fetching google like url descriptions in just one SQL query.

[see example](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=inurl%3Amaps.google.com%2Fsupport%3Fhl%3Den)

If description is greater than a fixed limit of characters say 100 characters then append '...' otherwise show the complete description.

My current SQL query is this:

```
 SELECT post_id, CONCAT( LEFT( post_text, 50 ) , '...' ) AS text FROM posts
```

Please suggest a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( length( post_text ) > 50, CONCAT( LEFT( post_text, 47 ) , '...' ), post_text )
```